# AVFoundation to take video swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation, video-capture

I have been following this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0O3ZGUS3pk and managed to get to the point where I can take photos, and see the camera output on my UIView.

However I need to record video instead of taking photos.  I have looked on stackOverflow and in the AVFoundation help, but couldn't get it to work.  This is my code so far:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    for device in devices! {
        if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput) {
                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                        captureSession.startRunning()
                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                        previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width/2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height/2)
                        previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.bounds
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func recordPress(_ sender: Any) {
    if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

    }
}
```

I saw a question on here relating to this tutorial, but it didnt have the answer.
How would you use the AVFoundation to record video in this way?

Comment: I can't see the **AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate** in your code, I think this will solve your problem, In case you still couldn't figure this out, I will explain to you.